# Adding submenu items to menuitems

Tags: c++, menu, win32gui

I was having trouble adding a submenu item to a menuitem to my window menu in C++. I was adding a number (20 to be exact) of saving slots for my game.

Here is the code I have for the save slots:

```
    HMENU win32MENU = CreateMenu();//Menu bar

    HMENU win32SETTINGS = CreateMenu();//Settings option
        HMENU win32SAVESLOTS = CreateMenu();//Save Slots

    AppendMenu(win32MENU,MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)win32SETTINGS,"Settings");

    //Settings
    AppendMenu(win32SETTINGS,MF_STRING,(UINT_PTR)win32SAVESLOTS,"Save                       Ctrl+S");

        //Save Slots
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Default ~");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 1");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 2");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 3");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 4");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 5");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 6");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 7");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 8");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 9");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 10");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 11");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 12");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 13");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 14");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 15");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 16");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 17");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 18");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 19");
        AppendMenu(win32SAVESLOTS,MF_STRING,NULL,"Save Slot 20");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe in what way this is not working? Also if you can get rid of all the code that *does* work, that will help focus on what doesn't.

Comment: It can't display another menu when I mouse-over the "Save" option. I would display an image to show what I mean, but SO won't let me do it because I am new. I can sure do that. Hold on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

`AppendMenu(win32SETTINGS,MF_STRING,(UINT_PTR)win32SAVESLOTS,"Save                       Ctrl+S");`

to

`AppendMenu(win32SETTINGS,MF_STRING | MF_POPUP,(UINT_PTR)win32SAVESLOTS,"Save                       Ctrl+S");`

Also, change

`HMENU win32SAVESLOTS = CreateMenu();//Save Slots`

to

`HMENU win32SAVESLOTS = CreatePopupMenu();//Save Slots`